# Let a, b, c be randomly chosen (in order, and with replacement) from the set {1, 2, 3, . . . , 999}.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, c$ be randomly chosen (in order, and with replacement) from the set {${1, 2, 3, . . . , 999}$}.
If each choice is equally likely, what is the probability that $a^2 + bc$ is divisible by $3$?

What I've noticed in this problem was that if $3|a$, then we have $3|bc$. And if $3\nmid{a}$, then $bc$ should be $2\:mod\:3$ and $1\:mod\:3$. I don't know how to progress from here.

Comment: If $a=3$, $b=2$ and $c=5$ then $3|a\not \Rightarrow 3|bc$

Comment: @DavidPeterson With the assumtion that $3\mid a^2 + bc$, the implication holds.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a more general result:

If

$\Pr(a = 0 \bmod 3) = \Pr(a = 1 \bmod 3) = \Pr(a = 2 \bmod 3) = \frac{1}{3}$
$\Pr(b = 0 \bmod 3) = \Pr(b = 1 \bmod 3) = \Pr(b = 2 \bmod 3) = \frac{1}{3}$
$\Pr(c = 0 \bmod 3) = \Pr(c = 1 \bmod 3) = \Pr(c = 2 \bmod 3) = \frac{1}{3}$

then

$\Pr(a^2 + bc = 0 \bmod 3) = \frac{1}{3}$

This is easy to prove/verify.